# Passing values to a modal windows function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, modal-dialog

I have a list of buttons. Each button is assigned an ID (PK) that can be used to delete an item from the database. Code is below.

```
htp.tableData('<button class = "DELETE" value = '||patch_id||'>DEL</button>');
```

I want to be able to capture a reason for DELETE, so upon clicking the button, I have a modal window pop up that says, "Please enter a delete reason".

```
dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               height: 400,
               width: 580,
               show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 },
               modal: true,
               buttons: {
                 "Submit": RunDeleteAjax,

                 Cancel: function() {
                   dialog.dialog( "close" );
                 }
               },
               close: function() {
                 form[ 0 ].reset();
                 allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
               }
             });
```

Notice that there is a function called "RunDeleteAjax". This function is responsible for an AJAX call that calls a procedure to delete the ID. I have one problem: I am not sure how to grab the id of the button that I clicked. I'm not sure if I can pass it to the modal window somehow or even to the function being called. I am able to grab the value of the button I clicked using the following:

```
$(".DELETE").on("click", function() { 
       var _btnVal = $( this ).attr("value")
       dialog.dialog( "open" );
  });
```

But from that point, how can I pass it to the modal window or if thats even possible. Because once I can, I can just use it as a parameter in my "RunDeleteAjax" function.

Also, the actual modal form code is below:

```
<div id="dialog-form" class="dform" title="">
        <p class="validateTips">Please provide a detailed description of your changes.</p>

          <form>
            <fieldset>

              <label for="textarea">Reason</label>
              <textarea rows="4" cols ="75" name="EditReason" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></textarea>

              <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
              <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>');
```

ANy help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide example markup for a button? I think you'd want to grab the id of the button you clicked onclick with JS and whittle off the part of the value you don't need with `substring()` or `split()` using a delimiter of some kind like the dash in 'button-23412'. That remaining value would be the value you'd want to pass to `RunDeleteAjax()`, but I'm not sure if that's how it's set up.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I found a solution to this issue. I wanted to post this just in case anyone else had a similar problem. I needed to utilize Jquery's .data method and append the value (I was already capturing) to my "dialog".

```
 $("#dialog-form").data("param", _btnVal).dialog( "open" );
```

Now that I have it attached to my 'Dialog", I can use the value. I was able to grab the value and pass it to my RunDeleteAjax function. I needed to update the 'buttons' section as well.

```
buttons: {
                 "Submit": function() {

                   var _gts = $( this ).data("param");
                   RunDeleteAjax(_gts);
                 },

                 Cancel: function() {
                   dialog.dialog( "close" );
                 }
               },
```

As I was browsing around for answers, I saw several different ways to do this. Based on what I was trying to do, the adjustments I made above worked best for me.